# Adding text to JTextArea box when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener, jtextarea

Okay so I am trying to figure out how to add text into a TextArea when a certain button is clicked in my GUI. For this current problem, When i click the reset button I want it to display a few lines of text that i have prewritten already. I am not sure how i would implement this into my applet.

here is my code for the the button

```
public class DisplayButtonPanel2 extends JPanel{

//create buttons for reseting back to original data, displaying data and sorting data
JButton resebutton = new JButton("RESET");
JButton displaybutton = new JButton("DISPLAY");  
JButton sortbutton = new JButton("SORT"); 

//constructor 
public DisplayButtonPanel2()
{

      //create action listener object
  BListen listener = new BListen();

      //add action listen functionalty to buttons
  resebutton.addActionListener(listener);
  displaybutton.addActionListener(listener);
  sortbutton.addActionListener(listener);

     //add buttons to panel
  add(resebutton);
  add(displaybutton);
  add(sortbutton);

}

public class BListen implements ActionListener
{

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

     if (event.getSource() == resebutton){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"reset Button Clicked");
        DisplayEmployeePanel displayemply = new DisplayEmployeePanel();
        displayemply.resetText();


     }

     else if(event.getSource() == displaybutton){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"display Button Clicked");
       // DisplayEmployeePanel displayemply = new DisplayEmployeePanel();
     }
     else if(event.getSource() == sortbutton){

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"sort Button Clicked");
     }


  }
```

}

code for the textArea

```
public class DisplayEmployeePanel extends JPanel{


//create a text area that will display employees

JTextArea employeetextarea = new JTextArea("~Company Employee's~", 20 ,30);          //textinarea, hieght, width



 //constructor
 public DisplayEmployeePanel()
 {

   employeetextarea.setEditable(false);   //will not be able to edit text in area

  String ns = "\nDisplay Employee Info BELOW";
  employeetextarea.append(ns);



  //add text area to panel
  add(employeetextarea);


}

public void resetText()
{

  String sn = "\nreset to original emmployee list";
  employeetextarea.append(sn);
  add(employeetextarea);
  System.out.println("reset text");///testing purposes

 }



 }//end class
```

EDIT* adding in more source code if that helps, 
this code for creating frame

```
 public class CreateCompanyGUI extends JFrame{

 //constructor
 public CreateCompanyGUI()
 {
   super("Company Applet!");                                      //tittle
  setSize(800,800);                                              //set size  *careful when using pack*
  setLocationRelativeTo(null);                                   //places frame in middle of screen by default
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                //how to close
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());                                 //set BorderLayout manager for this frame


  //create panels
  DisplayEmployeePanel dep = new DisplayEmployeePanel();
  //  DisplayEmployeePanel2 dep2 = new DisplayEmployeePanel2();
  DisplayButtonPanel dbp = new DisplayButtonPanel();
  DisplayButtonPanel2 dbp2 = new DisplayButtonPanel2();
 // DisplayListPanel dlp = new DisplayListPanel();


  //add panels to frame
  add(dep, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  add(dbp2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(dbp, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 // add(dlp, BorderLayout.EAST);
 // add(dep2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  //pack (packs the window and creates appporiate size
  pack();
  //visible = TRUE (so we can see the frame)
  setVisible(true);


}



}//end class
```

code for creating GUI

```
public class CompanyApplet extends JApplet{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
     //create GUI for company applet
      new CreateCompanyGUI();


  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    DisplayEmployeePanel displayemply = new DisplayEmployeePanel();
    displayemply.resetText();
```

You can't keep creating a new DisplayEmployeePanel. You want to update the textarea of the existing panel that is visible on the GUI. Then means that the DisplayButtonPanel2, needs a reference to the DisplayEmployeePanel.

So in your code where you create the two panels and add them to the frame you need to pass the DisplayEmployeedPanel as a parmameter to the DisplayButtonPanel2.

Or the simpler solution is to just have a single class that create the two panels. Then all the methods in that class have access to all the components defined in the class.

Comment: I figured i was doing something wrong when creating a new DisplayEmployeePanel in DisplayButtonPanel2 class, so how would i pass the DisplayEmployeePanel ? something like

 DisplayEmployeePanel dep = new DisplayEmployeePanel(); 
DisplayButtonPanel2 dbp2 = new DisplayButtonPanel2();

dbp2(dep);

?

Comment: @S.Q, I suggest you start by reading your text book on how to create classes and pass parameters. You can't program unless you read the basics in your text book. For example look at your code for creating a JButton. You pass in the text to display on the button. Well that is an example of creating a class and passing in parameters. This is no different.

Comment: haha I understand how to create a class etc...its just im not familar with creating GUI using these Swing, events, awt components in Java, i have never done this type of programming. thank you though.

Comment: @S.Q, This has nothing to do specifically with Swing. All you are doing is creating an Object and passing a parameter to the Object. In this case the Object you are creating is your DisplayButtonPanel and you pass a reference of your DisplayEmployeePanel as a parameter.